# Missing MaterialUI Table Props in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, storybook

I'm using MaterialUI which I slightly modify (styling/logic) in order to create a custom library.  I'm also using Storybook (with Typescript) to create documentation.

The problem I'm facing is that the storybook table props are not always automatically generated.  It only shows the props I added, but none of the ones built by material UI. For example:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import MuiPaper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import clsx from "clsx";

export interface PaperProps extends MuiPaperProps {
    /**
     * If `true`, a darker background will be applied.
     * @default false
     */
    filled?: boolean;
    /**
     * If `true`, the border around the Paper will be removed.
     * @default false
     */
    disableOutline?: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    root: {
        borderRadius: "8px",
        border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[200]}`,
        "&$filled": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[100],
        },
        "&$disableOutline": {
            border: "none",
        },
    },
    /* Pseudo-class applied to the root element if `disableOutline={true}`. */
    disableOutline: {},
    /* Pseudo-class applied to the root element if `filled={true}`. */
    filled: {},
}));

export const Paper: React.FC<PaperProps> = (props) => {
    const { disableOutline = false, filled = false, ...restProps } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MuiPaper
            classes={classes}
            className={clsx(classes.root, {
                [classes.disableOutline]: disableOutline,
                [classes.filled]: filled,
            })}
            {...restProps}
        />
    );
};
```

**Screenshots**
[image: missing material-ui table props in storybook canvas]

[image: missing material-ui table props in storybook docs]

On the other hand, it works perfectly with MuiButton which is very strange. I can't figure out why it doesn't work with Paper.

[image: material UI interface table props display correctly in storyboard docs]

Comment: does your Button has its own interface or are you using the one exported by MuiButton?
probably related https://github.com/strothj/react-docgen-typescript-loader/issues/47

Comment: Using own interface, which is an extension of MuiButtonProps. I do the same for Paper and it doesn't work...

Comment: D: interesting, I think it shouldn't work for Button neither, could you provide a reproducible example repo to investigate further? that will also be useful for getting help in the issues section of the official storybook repo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I got to debug this thoroughly and found out that typescript's [default configuration](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/typescript) excludes all types from `node_modules` for docgen with this filter

`propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),`

However, for some reason, probably the way MuiButtonProps type is written, the `prop.parent` is undefined for MuiButton props and let them pass.

Since you want to include all MaterialUI's props you can modify the default filter in `.storybook/main.js` this way:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: "react-docgen-typescript",
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => {
        return prop.parent
          ? /@material-ui/.test(prop.parent.fileName) ||
              !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName)
          : true;
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, I tried this and it seems to only work on a few components. For instance, the "Paper" or "LinearPropgress" custom components don't seem to have additional MaterialUI props generated in the tables...

Comment: @Skoltz do you mean that even with the config you're still not getting the Paper props in the table? because in the repo I set up is working just fine

Comment: For anyone using material-ui 5, replace "@material-ui" with "@mui" in the above codeblock